# Setting ListView ItemsPanel Duplicates Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a custom control in my application. One of the dependency properties is an `ObservableCollection<ToggleButton>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<ToggleButton> HeaderButtons
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ToggleButton>)GetValue(HeaderButtonsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderButtonsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderButtonsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderButtons", typeof(ObservableCollection<ToggleButton>), typeof(Expandable), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ToggleButton>()));
```

I'm then putting them in a `ListView` in `Generic.xaml`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding HeaderButtons}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

...and using it like this:

```
<controls:MyControl.HeaderButtons>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="FilterButton">
        <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/Empty Filter-512.png" Height="15" Width="15"/>
    </ToggleButton>
</controls:MyControl.HeaderButtons>
```

However, I keep ending up with a duplicate item:

[image: Duplicate item]

I can't figure out how that item is getting there. I can fix it by removing my custom `ListView.ItemsPanel`, but of course that makes my items flow vertically, defeating the entire purpose. Can anyone else see why this would be duplicating the item?

EDIT: For further interest, if I go into the Live Visual Tree I can see that both buttons have the name "FilterButton". Which should, of course, not be possible.

EDIT: Here's the `ContentPresenter` from the `MainWindow`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentControl, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

And `CurrentControl` is set to an instance of my `UserControl`:

```
private UserControl currentControl;
public UserControl CurrentControl
{
    get { return currentControl; }
    set
    {
        if (currentControl != value)
        {
            currentControl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentControl");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird. I have just tested your code with the only difference being the image and no problems just 1 image shows up.

Comment: what happens when you throw another `ToggleButton` in there? 4 items?

Comment: @SWilko Strange... For further reference, I'm utilizing the control inside a `UserControl` which is hosted inside a `ContentPresenter` in the `MainWindow`. And yes, I get 4 items.

Comment: You could post the `MainWindow` xaml including UserControl code and I'll try to test it if its not huge :)

Comment: @SWilko Posted relevant code.

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with that code. I would strip out the `UserControl` and `ContentPresenter`. Put the `CustomControl` directly in `MainWindow` to see if you still get duplicates and go from there. Sorry I haven't been more help

Comment: @SWilko Curiouser and Curiouser... That gives me *three* buttons. That gives me a little more info than I had... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is the default value of your `HeaderButtonsProperty` - you set one using `new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ToggleButton>())`. Contrary to what you expect it does not create one instance of the collection for each instance of your control, but a single instance shared across all of your controls.

Then you use this XAML syntax:

```
<controls:MyControl.HeaderButtons>
    <ToggleButton (...) />
</controls:MyControl.HeaderButtons>
```

which does not assign a new collection to your `HeadersButton` property, but rather adds the specified item to the existing one. So each time this part of code is "executed", it adds a new copy of the `ToggleButton` to the single collection shared by all your controls.

To resolve the problem you should remove the default value from your `HeaderButtonsProperty`'s metadata and assign a new collection instance in your control's constructor - that way each control instance will have it's own independent collection.